# record 120 sec video and want to reduce size up to 3-4 MB in Android

Tags: android, video, compression, video-streaming, lossless-compression

i want to record 120 sec video from my application and want video size only to 3-4 MB maximum, so is there any way to reduce that instead of using FFmpeg ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is possible whilst still making it look good.

A video with a size of 300 x 300 px, a color-depth of 16 bits and 10 frames per second (which isn't to good looking and not very smooth), takes ~200 mb uncompressed: `(300 * 300 * 16 * 10 * 120) / (8*1024*1024)`
Scaling that down to 4 mb would be a compression of 5000%. I might be wrong with my math and trying the answer of @mehul might be good to start with but I guess it won't be possible. But again, try it, I might be wrong.
You can - of course - reduce the quality I mentioned above but I don't know if that is wanted by you (For example, half the colors and 8 fps results in 82 mb uncompressed).